# Wordpress 4.5 update Issue

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using KLEO themeforest theme on [my blog](http://www.pyxel.co.uk/blog/)  which I recently updated to WordPress version 4.5. It looks good in the beginning but now the homepage and category archive pages are not showing posts. The individual blog posts are appearing as usual.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Regards
Abdullah

Answer (score 0):

Issue in css 
See below screenshot : http://prntscr.com/atrbrm

```
.kleo-transform .animated.animate-when-visible, .kleo-transform .animated.animate-when-almost-visible, .cul {
    opacity: 1;
}
.kleo-transform .one-by-one-animated .el-appear, .kleo-transform .multi-columns-row .one-by-one-animated .el-appear, .kleo-transform .kleo-thumbs-animated.th-appear img, .kleo-transform .el-appear {
    opacity: 1;
    /*transform: scale(0.5);*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your theme version for compatibility. According to the theme changelog, Version 4.0.5 – 13.04.2016 is the first version compatible with WP 4.5. So you may need to update:
http://themeforest.net/item/kleo-next-level-wordpress-theme/6776630#item-description__changelog